# $\{0,1\}^{\omega}$ is not compact

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

$\{0,1\}^{\omega}$ is not compact. I proved a more difficult result that $[0,1]^{\omega}$ is not compact in the box topology and was told my proof was similar to this. However, I think it would be good practice to try this result as well. $\{0,1\}$ is in the discrete topology. Let $C$ be the collection of all points in $\{0,1\}^{\omega}$.  Consider the open cover of $\{0,1\}^{\omega}$ given by $\{\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}U_{nx}\}_{x \in C}$, where for each $x=(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $C$, a corresponding open set $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}U_{nx}$ containing it is defined by

$$U_{nx}=\begin{cases}   \{1\}   &\text{ if } x_n=1 \\
          \{0\}  & \ \text{if} \ x_n=0\end{cases}$$

Then $x \in \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}U_{nx}$ and if $y \in C-\{x\}$ there is an index $k$ such that $x_k \notin U_{ky}$ and $x \notin \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}U_{ny}$. So if $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}U_{nx}$ is taken out of the cover, the element $x \in \{0,1\}^{\omega}$ is not covered by $\{\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}U_{nx}\}_{x \in C}-\{\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}U_{nx}\}$. Since $\{\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}U_{nx}\}_{x \in C}$ is an infinite cover, and taking one element of this collection out results in a noncover, $\{0,1\}^{\omega}$ is not compact.

One thing I had difficulty showing is that the collection $\{\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}U_{nx}\}_{x \in C}$ actually covers $\{0,1\}^{\omega}$. How could I show that the union of elements in the cover is equal to $\{0,1\}^{\omega}$ explicitly? Also, would this be the correct way to do this proof? I modeled the solution after this solutions, in which I was provided help. [Proving $[0,1]^{\omega}$ in box topology is not compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4065039/proving-0-1-omega-in-box-topology-is-not-compact)

Comment: Are you talking about the box topology on the product? That topology is easily shown to be discrete, and since the product is certainly infinite, that immediately implies that it is not compact.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yea the box topology on the product. Would $\{0,1\}^{\omega}$ be compact or not with the product topology?

Comment: In that case just note that $\prod_nU_{nx}=\{x\}$ for each, so the box product is discrete. (Of course that does also give you an infinite irreducible open cover, since each point is contained in exactly one of the open sets of that form.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott can my proof that $[0,1]^{\omega}$ be easily generalized to proving that $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is not compact with the box topology? Would the same proof prove this?

Comment: You don’t need to generalize it: $[0,1]^\omega$ with the box topology is a closed subset of $\Bbb R^\omega$ with the box topology, so if the latter were compact, the former would also be compact, and it’s not.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott and that is because $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is Hausdorff, with the box topology?

Comment: No, it’s because every closed subset of a compact space is compact, irrespective of separation axioms. It’s the other direction for which you need the space to be Hausdorff: a compact subset of a Hausdorff space is always closed, but a compact subset of a non-Hausdorff space need not be closed.

Answer (score 1):

That it covers is trivial: $x \in \prod_n U_{nx}=: U_x$ for each $x \in C$.
In fact $U_x=\{x\}$ is open in the box topology, showing that all points of $\{0,1\}^\omega$ are isolated. $C$ is infinite (uncountable) and discrete.

The cover $\{U_x\mid  x\in C\}$ is irreducible: we cannot omit any $U_y$ because then $y$ will not be covered anymore. So the cover has no proper subcovers at all.

Nitpick: you can just say $U_{nx}=\{x_n\}$ and be done.